# Getting rid of 'netrw' plugin for vim

Tags: vim, netrw

I have no idea how 'netrw' works, nor how it got enabled on my vim. I want to get rid of it, or the very least learn how to run a 'c' file one it.

I have tried adding

```
let loaded_netrwPlugin = 1
```

to my `~/.vimrc` file.

I have tried returning my vim back to default, with great failure. I have tried just about everything on the internet to get rid of it so I can test my homework on the flip server. But the strange plugin is still there and I can't figure out how to work it.

I am used to just going `vim <folder_name>` then `clang <my_project.c>` then `./a.out` to run it. What happened to those good old days? 
Thank you for any help. I have tried so many things and nothing is really working out.

This is what I see when I vim my CS-261, I just want to be able to open assignment_1 and compile my assignments in there.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686729/vim-how-to-remove-netrw

Comment: What do you mean you're used to "*going `vim <folder_name>`*"? Why are you running vim on a directory name?

Comment: @melpomene Some editors allow users to open directories. What you get is more or less a text-based file-manager. The only thing I don't get is what the OP expects to have once `netrw` is removed or otherwise disabled. When I tried it here, `vim` complained when I tried to run it on a directory. Disabling `netrw` essentially removed file management capabilities from `vim`.

Answer (score -1):

I don’t see where you would need `vim` for the actions you want to do. Just run

```sh
cd <folder_name>
clang <my_project.c>
./a.out
```